# How to use a self-signed certificate which i get as JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, authentication, certificate

From a request i get a JSON like this:

```
    {
    "authentications": [
        {
            "type": "clientCertificate",
            "secret": "...",
            "pem": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
                    abc..
                    -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
                    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                    abc...
                    -----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I have to create a certificate out of this and use it to comunicate to the Server. Does anybody can help me please?

Comment: There is something **SERIOUSLY** wrong here. The peer is sending you not only a self-signed certificate but a private key. This is a *prima facie* security violation. It should not be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like PEM. You can read PEM with [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).

UPDATE:

Here is an example of how you read a key pair with a certificat chain:

```
        PEMReader in = new PEMReader(reader, dlg);
        Object obj = in.readObject();
        if (obj == null) {
            // Some PEM files have garbarge at the top
            for (int i = 0; i < 9 && obj == null; ++i) {
                obj = in.readObject();
            }
        }
        keys = null;
        if (obj instanceof KeyPair) {
            keys = (KeyPair)obj;
            obj = in.readObject();
        }
        List<X509Certificate> list = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
        while (obj != null) {
            if (obj instanceof X509Certificate) {
                list.add((X509Certificate)obj);
            }
            obj = in.readObject();
        }
```